# Rails: Open a login modal from a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building an ecommerce app, and have a pretty standard user model and order model. For a user to place an order they must first be logged in. I'm using a Bootstrap modal for the standard login\signup forms.

I'm trying to find a way for when a **signed out** visitor clicks the Order Now button (links to /orders/new) to have the login\signup modal appear, and then after they log in they'll be redirected to /orders/new path.

Here's my current Orders#new method:

```
 def new
   @order = Order.new
   if current_user
     @order.user = current_user
     @order.docs.build
   else
     redirect_to new_order_path
   end
 end
```

Here's my current Users#new and Users#create methods. I used [this guide](http://www.jetthoughts.com/blog/tech/2014/08/27/5-steps-to-add-remote-modals-to-your-rails-app.html) to setup the modals.

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  respond_modal_with @user
end

def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  respond_modal_with @user, location: root_path
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
     format.html {
       login(params[:user][:email], params[:user][:password])
       UserMailer.send_signup_email(@user).deliver_later
       redirect_to root_path, notice: "You have successfully signed up"
       }
     format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
    else
      format.html { render :new, alert: "Registration failed" }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Sorry if I'm missing important info here. It's my first time posting and I'm a newbie. Thanks in advance for your help!

**Edit:**
Comments were recommending I use Devise for authorization, and I should have mentioned that I'm already using Sorcery for my authentication\authorization. So that part of the problem isn't an issue. The trouble I'm having is just how to trigger the modal from the Orders controller. Thanks!

Comment: You need to check if the user is already logged, and then do the redirection within the sign_up method or any other you're using to log them, you can use Devise or make your own authentication. But difficult to see what's wrong because there's no code of your views, try adding them.

Comment: thanks @SebastiánPalma! I am using Sorcery for auth. I'll try approaching it by redirecting from the User controller instead of the Orders controller. Cheers!

Comment: I've seen that unlike Devise, Sorcery used the `logged_in?` method to check for logged users.

Answer (score 1):

Hi if you want to add functionality such as login/signup and perform all those operations, I would recommend you to use 'devise' gem. It is very easy and handy to use. You can find its documentation [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise).  It has several methods like user_signed_in? which will help your problem signed out user to show login page and then continue your modal operation.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks Aashish! I'm using Sorcery for auth. already, so I'll take a look at their docs and see if they suggest a way to solve this. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

To do this in a DRY way using Devise you can use the `StoreLocation` module. see the code: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/7d3d6fb3f04caea95e343956a88654f753b45af4/lib/devise/controllers/store_location.rb

To use that, you can follow the instructions from their WIKI: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in

Pretty much, you will have to:

1.Create a filter in your application_controller to redirect to sign-in page and save the current path:

```
def ensure_logged_in_or_redirect
  unless logged_in?
    store_location_for(:user, request.path)
    redirect_to new_user_session_path
  end
end
```

2.Create the `after_sign_in_path_for` method also in the application_controller, as shown on the Wiki.

3.Call that `ensure_logged_in_or_redirect` filter before the actions you want to protect, like the 'New Order' one.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Arthur! I found a solution, but I'm sure it's not the best approach. I'll revisit it when I have time to clean up the code. Cheers!